# Facebook API error about migrate to OAuth2

Tags: facebook

I am getting this Facebook API error:

> API Error Code: 100
>   API Error Description: Invalid parameter
>   Error Message: Please migrate to OAuth2 and use new /dialog/oauth endpoint. return_session is no longer available.

However, I set the variable for Facebook API keys and API secret. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the newest PHP SDK?

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk

My guess is that you are using an older version (2.x), so you should upgrade. If that does not help, take a look at the login docs:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestions.